# Auto Zoom mapView based on the two different co-ordinates

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I can able to show markers on Google maps when they are near to eachother, but when the distance between is high, I can able to see only one lat&lon.

Here is my code

```
   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    LatLng google_api_lat_lon = new LatLng(lat, lon);
    float zoomLevel = 16.0f;
    Marker markerAPILocation = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(google_api_lat_lon).title(title).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.saved_locaitons)));
    markerAPILocation.showInfoWindow();
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(google_api_lat_lon, zoomLevel));
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    //  mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(google_api_lat_lon, zoomLevel));
}
```

I need to show two co-ordinates in the map it can be achieved only by adjusting zoom level based on the distance. I tried above code but its not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by simply adding,

```
   LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    builder.include(google_api_lat_lon);
    builder.include(current_lat_lon);
    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 10));
```